# Хостинг и удаленное подключение к MySQL

Tags: mysql, безопасность, хостинг

На FTP расположен сайт и БД (в определенной директории), и БД относится к сайту как `localhost`.

Как мне подключиться удаленно?

У меня есть полный доступ к FTP ну и собственно данные БД.
Хочу подключиться через Workbench.

Comment: Так может у хостера спросить или faq у него же почитать? На моём хостинге, например, удалённый доступ к базе запрещён.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно ip твоего сервера(хостинга) где лежит сайт, если для сайта localhost бд, то значит они на одном ip. Так и подключаешься, единственное у некоторых хостеров в личном кабинете есть пункт, который разрешает\запрещает удаленное подключение к БД, если пункта нет, напиши им и скажи хочу удаленно подключатся и будет тебе счастье.

Answer (score 4):

если ваш хостинг-план не дает возможность доступа через ssh и запрещает удаленный доступ напрямую к БД - никак (кроме очень извращенных решений)

крайне не рекомендую заниматься подобными вещами, если вы не готовы правильно настроить ssl для подключения к mysql, запретить подключение без ssl  и т.д. просто потому, что без ssl все ваши данные будут передаваться в открытом виде, а подключиться с перебором паролей или каким-нибудь багом в mysql/криво настроенными правами сможет кто угодно

правильный хостинг запретит подключение к бд не из локальной сети.

три варианта:

- если у вас есть возможность подключаться по ssh к хостингу, можете пробросить соединение через ssh-туннель к mysql, можете подключить локальный mysql-клиент типа mysql-workbench/phpmyadmin (но обычно доступ с phpmyadmin итак предоставляется) Проброс ssh-туннеля будет не очень быстрым, но вполне реальным и безопасным решением.
- логинитесь на хостинг  в ssh и уже через него работаете в консольном mysql-клиенте. Быстро, но если вам очень нужен workbench - не очень удобно.
- если у вас облачный хостинг виртуальной машины типа digital ocean или выделенный сервер, можете поставить что-нибудь вроде openvpn, добавить свой клиентский компьютер в сеть и разрешить любые соединения внутри виртуальной сети. Безопасно и быстро.

У вас может возникнуть искушение разрешить логин в mysql только с определенных ip-адресов, но все ваши данные будут все равно пролетать по интернету в открытом виде

если вам очень нужен прямой доступ в базу данных  с помощью workbench и вы часто копаетесь в бд, то, может быть, вам следует развернуть копию сайта на своем компьютере - с помощью wamp/lamp/docker, тогда вы сможете экспериментировать с базой перед тем как проапдейтить сайт.

p.s. большинство профессиональных кодеров, которых я знаю, работают с бд через консольный клиент, а workbench используется для того, чтобы

- проверить ошибки синтаксиса (он весьма удобно отмечает строчку с ошибкой)
- отформатировать запрос в красивый вид (ctrl+b)

p.p.s
что значит  "БД (в определенной директории)"? вы можете через фтп видеть файлы базы данных?

Answer (score 0):

В общем: [Настройка удаленного подключения к MySQL](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/11.html)

конкретный случай зависит от вашего хостинга